# windows kafka java.nio.file.FileSystemException

Tags: apache-kafka

Very frequently error in windows server 2012

kafka verson 2.3.1

the error log

```
[2019-12-05 03:57:51,567] ERROR Uncaught exception in scheduled task 'kafka-log-retention' (kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.KafkaStorageException: Error while deleting segments for MetadataLog-0 in dir D:\GpsPlatform\kafka\.\tmp\kafka-logs
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\GpsPlatform\kafka\.\tmp\kafka-logs\MetadataLog-0\00000000000003368617.index -> D:\GpsPlatform\kafka\.\tmp\kafka-logs\MetadataLog-0\00000000000003368617.index.deleted: 另一个程序正在使用此文件，进程无法访问。

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:395)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:292)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1425)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:815)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.renameTo(AbstractIndex.scala:209)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.changeFileSuffixes(LogSegment.scala:509)
    at kafka.log.Log.asyncDeleteSegment(Log.scala:1982)
    at kafka.log.Log.deleteSegment(Log.scala:1967)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$deleteSegments$3(Log.scala:1493)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$deleteSegments$3$adapted(Log.scala:1493)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$deleteSegments$2(Log.scala:1493)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcI$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcI$sp.java:23)
    at kafka.log.Log.maybeHandleIOException(Log.scala:2085)
    at kafka.log.Log.deleteSegments(Log.scala:1484)
    at kafka.log.Log.deleteOldSegments(Log.scala:1479)
    at kafka.log.Log.deleteRetentionMsBreachedSegments(Log.scala:1557)
    at kafka.log.Log.deleteOldSegments(Log.scala:1547)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$cleanupLogs$3(LogManager.scala:914)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$cleanupLogs$3$adapted(LogManager.scala:911)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.cleanupLogs(LogManager.scala:911)
    at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$startup$2(LogManager.scala:395)
    at kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler.$anonfun$schedule$2(KafkaScheduler.scala:114)
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:65)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    Suppressed: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\GpsPlatform\kafka\.\tmp\kafka-logs\MetadataLog-0\00000000000003368617.index -> D:\GpsPlatform\kafka\.\tmp\kafka-logs\MetadataLog-0\00000000000003368617.index.deleted: 另一个程序正在使用此文件，进程无法访问。

        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:309)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:292)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1425)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:812)
        ... 29 more
```

after running for a period of time, a similar exception will be reported, causing Kafka to crash. How to completely resolve this exception?

Comment: Kafka isn't fully supported on windows. It'd be best to run within a VM or container

Comment: you mean using docker???

Comment: Yes, docker or a VM..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use kafka in windows environment. You have to disable log retention.
In Kafka server.properties

```
         log.retention.hours=-1
         log.cleaner.enable=false

#    Remove any other rows start from log.retention.*
```

Comment: but then the log file will get too bigger

Comment: Yes and this is side effect. If you are using windows maybe you can try docker desktop and install kafka in docker container

Comment: For smooth running kafka in windows machine, need to install WSL2. As kafka broker is going for deletion of older record as a part of improving the performance it will start rolling a segment file, here it will crash the broker. Since the kafka broker uses features of POSIX specifications. https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Answer (score 0):

To run Kafka on Windows it's recommended to do so using WSL2 as detailed [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2). Otherwise you encounter the kind of problems described above.